What is the difference between Tolerance Interval and Control Limits?
I understand that a tolerance interval indicates a range within which a specified percentage of a population (future value) is expected to fall.
Control limits, on the other hand, represent the acceptable range of variation within a process and are used to monitor if a process is operating within its normal variability. They help detect potential issues if data points fall outside these limits.
What I am unsure about, is whether control limits serve as a predictor for future values. If my process is stable, should all future values not fall within the UCL and LCL? Then how is the tolerance interval different from control limits?

There are really 3 concepts at play here; Specification Limits (sometimes also called Tolerance Limits), Control Limits, and Tolerance Intervals. They are loosely related, but are really 3 very different items.
The Specification/Tolerance Limits are, in a sense, the Voice of the customer; they define what the customer will accept (or what the producer will ship). Say you make a shaft of length 10cm; you specification is $10\pm.5$, so your Specification Limits are 9.5, 10.5. YOu use these to determine which shafts you can ship (inside the Specification Limits), or have to reject (too short, or too long). You rarely change these, unless the market demands it, They are not really based on any statistical calculation, but on the demand of the market.
The Control Limits are the Voice of the process; they help you detect "special causes" of variation, from "common causes" (see wiki). They are used exclusively on process Control Charts (aka Shewhart charts). Traditionally (based on Shewhart's recommendations), they are set at $\pm 3 \sigma$, where $\sigma$ is the standard deviation of your process (there are subtelties, but for this answer, we can leave it at that). It is purely a heuristic, i.e. something empirical, that practitioners have demonstrated that "it works". There are then rules which are used to determine, from the Control Chart, whether we should investigate a special cause, or not. Note that rules alert process engineers not just when a measurement is outside the $\pm\sigma$ limits; e.g. eight consecutive points on the same side of the centerline (even if very close to the nominal).
Ideally, one would like the Control Limits to be well within the Specification/Tolerance Limits. But this may, or not, be the case. When that is the case, you have a so-called "capable process". There are indexes to measure how well (or not) the Control Limits fit inside the Specification/Tolerance Limits (Capability indexes, Cp, Pp, etc.; see here). And you get then into the realm of $6 \sigma$ etc. (which I will not get into; see wiki for details). If the process capability is low, this will mean that the manufacturer has to reject/scrap a lot of products.
Note that you recompute process Control Limits on a regular basis (annually, quarterly, monthly?; or whenever non-trivial changes are made on the production process and/or product) (unlike the Specification/Tolerance Limits). Ideally, as you areable to make your process more and more capable, you tighten the Control Limits, to dig deeper on reducing the variability (which is the whole point of process control).
Then you have Tolerance Intervals (TI). As you said, it is an interval in which you can find a certain proportion of the population of interest. For example, it may be that the 95% confidence tolerance interval for 95% coverage (i.e. proportion) of the above shafts is [9.8,10.4]. But the 99% confidence interval for 99% coverage would be [9.4,10.7]. You can compute TI's for any confidence level, and any proportion. It is a statistical result (similar to a Confidence Interval, but for a proportion, instead of e.g. a mean).
The Specification/Tolerance Limits, or the Control Limits are not based on any particular TI, or on any proportion of the population. YOu can show both Specification/Tolerance Limits (LSL, USL) and COntrol Limits (LCL, UCL) on the same Control Chart (it gives you a visual indicaton of how "capable" your process is). But placing a arbitrary Tolerance Interval on that chart does not serve any practical purpose.
